# Geometry Backfacing Node for Double-Sided Normals/Displacement?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm currently working on creating environment assets, and more specifically a vast array of plant material. As you can see in the photos, I'm using a "Geometry Backfacing node" as the mix factor between two textures which allows for a discrete front and a back to the material. The issue that I am running into comes when trying to achieve this for the normal/displacement maps. Nothing visible results concerning the normals with this setup. Any help with this is genuinely appreciated.

[image]

[image]